# in bash, heredoc inside function returns syntax error

Tags: bash, variables, sqlplus, heredoc, solaris-10

I have the following function:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_instance{
dbname=$(sqlplus -s / as sysdba<<EOF
set pages 0
set feedback off
select name from v\$database;
exit;
EOF)

echo $dbname

}

get_instance
```

It seems to work. In the middle of the error message, I get my `dbname`, but still returns a syntax error.

```
 oracle@testdb01:db01:/home/oracle/
 > ./test.sh
 ./test.sh: line 3: get_instance{: command not found
 DB01
 ./test.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
 ./test.sh: line 11: `}'
```

If I remove the function call completely, I get the result with no errors:

```
dbname=$(sqlplus -s / as sysdba<<EOF
set pages 0
set feedback off
select name from v\$database;
exit;
EOF)
echo $dbname

oracle@testdb01:db01:/home/oracle
> ./test.sh
DB01
```

What do I need to do to get this to work in a function?

### EDIT:

Following suggestion to place bracket after EOF tag and add function keyword:

```
 > vi test.sh
 "test.sh" 12 lines, 160 characters

#!/bin/bash
# updated file
function get_instance{
dbname=$(sqlplus -s / as sysdba<<EOF
set pages 0
set feedback off
select name from v\$database;
exit;
EOF
)
echo $dbname
}

get_instance

oracle@testdb01:db01:/home/oracle
> ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `dbname=$(sqlplus -s / as sysdba<<EOF
set pages 0
set feedback off
select name from v\$database;
exit;
EOF
)'
```

./test.sh: line 10: `)'

Comment: now, i may be mistaken, but doesnt heredoc use THREE `<`s ?

Comment: `EOF` should be on a line by itself, before the `)`

Comment: @MightyPork No. It's 2 <<.

Comment: @MightyPork no, that's something else (`cmd <<< "abc"` can be used as an alternative to `echo "abc" | cmd` in bash)

Comment: yeah ok, I know it from PHP so I assumed it'll be the standard syntax, apparently not

Comment: @TomFenech I just tried leaving EOF on its own at the end of heredoc but the error is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function declaration is wrong:

```
get_instance{
```

should be one of

```
function get_instance {
get_instance() {
```

---

Put the close bracket on a different line:

```
dbname=$(sqlplus -s / as sysdba<<EOF
...
EOF
)
```

The terminating word of the heredoc should be the only characters on the line (except tabs when using `<<-`). Demo:

```
$ x=$(cat <<END
> one
> two
> END)
bash: warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')
$ echo "$x"
one
two
```

So it worked, accidentally. Better practice is:

```
$ y=$(cat <<END
> 1
> 2
> END
> )
$ echo "$y"
1
2
```

Comment: Ah you're right about "function". I was wondering why it was still working. The code seems to just skips the problematic line and goes on.

Now it fails a little different still.

Comment: Are you on Solaris 10?

Comment: I think that we have slightly different system. I replaced function with get_instance(){} and that worked!

Also placing the ) after EOF.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: bash 4.2.53 on Linux (Fedora)

Comment: @ndefontenay the `function` syntax doesn't do anything useful and breaks compatibility. You may as well use the more widely compatible `func_name() {` syntax everywhere.

Comment: Meh. bash supports both. I find, generally, compatibility over-rated. How many different places do scripts tend to be installed? Almost always, one, in my experience.

Comment: I have to agree with @TomFenech The heredoc doesn't work very well when "function" is used. I had to go with functionname()