# Writing a Shell script

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a shell script that will essentially query a given condition. Here's the catch. I want it to repeat the query for a duration of 3 minutes. (probably run the query, and sleep for 2 seconds)

After 1 minute, at any time IF the query returns null, the for loop will break. (the main objective is to DETECT if the query returns the results consistently for a duration of 3 minutes)

How do I incorporate the checking for the BREAK statement in the below code, after 1 minute? (does SPOOL overwrite contents of files or does it append?)

```
for ((i=90; i > 1 ; i--))
    do
    sqlplus -s username/passwd@SERVICENAME <<EOF
    SET PAGESIZE 50000
    SET TERM OFF
    SET HEAD OFF
    SET LINESIZE 200
    #SET TRIMSPOOL ON
    SET FEEDBACK OFF

    SPOOL /appl/odd/local/bin/notification_pending.txt
    select awb,rcvr_phone,rcvr_email,latest_event,latest_event_dtm,status,contact,notify_method from shipment t,notification t2 where t.id=t2.shp_id
    and t2.status like 'F%'
    and t2.contact not in ('Recipient not in whitelist','Invalid Email Id','Mail Service Down','Invalid Mobile Number');

    SPOOL OFF
    exit
    /
    EOF
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: why not do this all in a stored package or procedure and call that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971833/in-bash-heredoc-inside-function-returns-syntax-error for some ideas. note the `dbname=$(...)` construct. Good luck.

Comment: @kevinsky, I am not using stored procedure because I believe in shell scripting, it will not be able to SPOOL the results out to a file and mail it as a notification.

Comment: @shelter, I'm familiar with the syntax and have no problem with it, but Im just not sure about writing the OTHER For Loop (or while loop) that checks and breaks off if a null result is returned, after X tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is capture the output of `sqlplus`, then test if the resulting string is empty or not. For readability, I'm putting the call to `sqlplus` in a function. Given the form of the `for` statement you are using, I'm also assuming that you are using `bash`.

```
run_query () {
sqlplus -s username/passwd@SERVICENAME <<EOF
# [deleted]
EOF
}

# SECONDS is incremented each second, so can be used as
# a simple timer.
SECONDS=0

# For the first minute, just run the query
while (( SECONDS <= 60 )); do
    output=$(run_query)
    sleep 2
done

# After the first minute, continue running the query for the
# next two minutes, but quit if the query produces no output.
while (( SECONDS <= 180 )); do
    output=$(run_query)
    if [[ -z $output ]]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

Or, you can combine the two loops and use a slightly more complicated conditional inside:

```
while (( SECONDS <= 180 )); do
    output=$(run_query)
    # Don't break for any reason during the first 60 seconds
    if ((SECONDS > 60)) && [[ -z $output ]]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

---

If you aren't using `bash`, you can simulate the timer with calls to `date`:

```
start=$(date +%s)
while now=$(date +%s); SECONDS=$(( now - start)); [ "$SECONDS" -le 180 ]; do
    output=$(run_query)
    if [ "$SECONDS" -gt 60 ] || [ -n "$output" ]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner! Does the -z in the if condition represent if the value is zero?

Comment: Zero length, that is if `$output == ""`.